# CNAME not pointing correctly

Tags: records, cname

I am using [getcloudapp.com](http://getcloudapp.com). I am trying to point my subdomain [cloud.chrisburton.me](http://cloud.chrisburton.me) to [proxy.cld.me](http://proxy.cld.me) however, it doesn't work on my desktop browser but it does on my iPhone.

Any ideas?

[Here is a screenshot of my records](http://f.cl.ly/items/0s391p2m1C2j282i0H0v/Image%202012-11-19%20at%2010.08.07%20AM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fairly long ttl on the DNS entries, so your desktop is most likely using a cached DNS record.  Your TTL looks like it is 14400, or 240 minutes.

Comment: I flushed my dns via the command prompt. Shouldn't that have cleared the cache?

Comment: That doesn't clear the cache at your DNS provider.  What does nslookup say?  (it may help to use a different DNS server, you can change it in nslookup by setting "server 8.8.8.8" to use google's if your not already)

Comment: Awesome! I changed my DNS settings to Google and it worked right away. Thank you!